# EF Core update-database Build Failed

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a very simple app, and thought I configured everything as it should.

I installed Entity Framework Core for SQL Server and Tools nuget packages.

I created 2 model classes:

```
public class Make
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}

public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Make Make { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Make")]
    public int MakeFK { get; set; }
}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Make> Makes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Model> Models { get; set; }
}
```

In `Program.cs` I added these lines of code:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```

And in `appsettings.json`, I added the connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source =localhost; Database=vRoom; Integrated Security=True; Pooling=False"
},
```

Now I did all this multiple times in the past and have had no issues. When I build I get no errors.

In the console I run:

```
 add-migration "initial"
```

Folder `Migrations` is created, with _initial, and also `Snapshot.cs` file.

After the first command I run:

```
 update-database
```

But I get a `BuildStart....` then `BuildFailed` error (nothing else)

I try to build the solution again and now I get an error. In the `Migrations Snapshot.cs` file there is something that was created and it gives me an error:

```
[DbContext(typeof(AppDbContext))]
```

Error says

> AppDbContext is a namespace but is used as a type

I have not seen this before even though I've ran probably a dozen migrations in my other app.

Any pointers?

EDIT: I noticed in my older project that I had EF 6.0.8, the version I'm using today is 6.0.9

Comment: And does your entire solution build without error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you got this error is class and namespace have the same name.

Your project structure may be：

```
namespace xxx.AppDbContext 
{
    public class AppDbContext 
    {
    }
}
```

The solution to this issue is make class and namespace have different name:

```
namespace xxx.MyDbContext 
    {
        public class AppDbContext 
        {
        }
    }
```

You can read [Do not name a class the same as its namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one) to Learn More details

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have folder structure like below:

Project > Model > AppDbContext

as per above folder structure you class was generated like below:

```
namespace Project.Model.AppDbContext // this name space cause your migration as per error message
{
   public class AppDbContext : DbContext
   {
       public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
       {
       }

       public DbSet<Make> Makes { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Model> Models { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Change your `namespace Project.Model.AppDbContext` with namespace `Project.Model.AppDbContextABC` then it will work fine.